# Esta a aparecer uma barra branca na margem direita causando o aparecimento do scroll horizontal

Tags: bootstrap

Estou com um erro e ja tentei de tudo para corrigir o problema que causa o aparecimento do scroll horizontal

http://amadeuantunes.com/

Comment: corrigi o <a> mas a div nao encontrei ainda

Comment: Estive a ver, e acho que é da barra de navegação, se fizer inspect consegue que o link "contacto" está fora

Comment: vou tirar a barra

Comment: resolvi essa div

Comment: tirei a barra, estou ja no d produção

Comment: ja tirei esse fecho

Comment: ainda não é isto que causava o raio daquela barra xD

Comment: Continua o problema?

Comment: Sim continua :/

Comment: Estranho, estou testando em diversas resoluções e está ok, tentou limpar o cache do seu browser?

Comment: LooL tinha feito refresh e nada mas agora fiz refresh e parece ter desaparecido

Comment: Então fechou!!!

Comment: Obrigado a s+erio ja estava farto disto xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem dois problemas no seu site, o primeiro é na sessão de portifólio, suas imagens estão explodindo, para corrigir adicione a seguinte regra no seu css:

```
.img-responsive {
    margin: 0;
}
```

O segundo problema é no rodapé, existe uma div com a classe `containe`, faltando o `r`.

Comment: resolvi o container

Comment: adicionei essa regra

Comment: Pelo que vi aqui zerou...